# Appium: automation Instrument doesn't work with iPhone 5S device (iOS 8.1), xCode 6.1, Appium 1.3

Tags: automation, iphone-5, appium, xcode6.1, ios8.1

My Environment:
MacOS: 10.9.5; 
Xcode: 6.1; 
Appium: 1.3; 
iPhone 5S device (iOS 8.1)

I've run Appium server with command:

```
Dmytros-Mac:bin dmytrohorban$ node appium.js -U 1e2c8589a84393e8c7b1fa801cbc69d6d3a9d222  --app /Users/dmytrohorban/Desktop/Test_builds/Device/TestQS.app;
```

Below server output:

```
info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.0 (REV 126591b2556e5e6e3ee8cc1711b8748274ffbde4)
info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"app":"/Users/dmytrohorban/Desktop/Test_builds/Device/TestQS.app","udid":"1e2c8589a84393e8c7b1fa801cbc69d6d3a9d222"}
info: Console LogLevel: debug
```

And run appium tests:

```
info: --> POST /wd/hub/session {"desiredCapabilities":{"platformVersion":"6.1","app":"/Users/dmytrohorban/Desktop/Test_builds/Device/TestQS.app","platformName":"iOS","deviceName":"iPhone 5S"}}
    info: Client User-Agent string: Apache-HttpClient/4.3.4 (java 1.5)
    info: [debug] Using local app from desired caps: /Users/dmytrohorban/Desktop/Test_builds/Device/TestQS.app
    info: [debug] Creating new appium session c091154b-63aa-4623-9759-ee060959f471
    info: [debug] Removing any remaining instruments sockets
    info: [debug] Cleaned up instruments socket /tmp/instruments_sock
    info: [debug] Setting Xcode folder
    info: [debug] Setting Xcode version
    info: [debug] Setting iOS SDK Version
    info: [debug] Getting sdk version from xcrun with a timeout
    info: [debug] iOS SDK Version set to 8.1
    info: [debug] Not checking whether simulator is available since we're on a real device
    info: [debug] Detecting automation tracetemplate
    info: [debug] Not auto-detecting udid, running on sim
    info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as binary) at /Users/dmytrohorban/Desktop/Test_builds/Device/TestQS.app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
    info: Will try to parse the plist file as XML
    `parseFileSync()` is deprecated. Use `parseStringSync()` instead.
    `parseStringSync()` is deprecated. Use `parse()` instead.
    info: [debug] Could not parse plist file (as XML) at /Users/dmytrohorban/Desktop/Test_builds/Device/TestQS.app/en.lproj/Localizable.strings
    warn: Could not parse app Localizable.strings; assuming it doesn't exist
    info: [debug] Getting bundle ID from app
    info: [debug] Parsed app Info.plist (as binary)
    info: [debug] Creating instruments
    info: On some xcode 6 platforms, instruments-without-delay does not work. If you experience this, you will need to re-run appium with the --native-instruments-lib flag
    info: [debug] Preparing uiauto bootstrap
    info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap dir: /Users/dmytrohorban/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap
    info: [debug] Dynamic env: {"nodePath":"/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.32/bin/node","commandProxyClientPath":"/Users/dmytrohorban/Desktop/appium/node_modules/appium-uiauto/bin/command-proxy-client.js","instrumentsSock":"/tmp/instruments_sock","interKeyDelay":null,"justLoopInfinitely":false,"autoAcceptAlerts":false}
    info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap code: // This file is automatically generated. D...ot manually modify!
    info: [debug] Dynamic bootstrap path: /Users/dmytrohorban/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-b578988031d7fc8c.js
    info: [debug] Reusing dynamic bootstrap: /Users/dmytrohorban/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-b578988031d7fc8c.js
    info: [debug] Getting device string from opts: {"forceIphone":false,"forceIpad":false,"xcodeVersion":"6.1","iOSSDKVersion":"8.1","deviceName":"iPhone 5S","platformVersion":"6.1"}
    info: [debug] fixDevice is on
    info: [debug] Final device string is: 'iPhone 5S (6.1 Simulator)'
    info: [debug] Not setting device type since we're on a real device
    info: [debug] Checking whether we need to set app preferences
    info: [debug] Not setting iOS and app preferences since we're on a real device
    info: [debug] Running ios sim reset flow
    info: [debug] Killing the simulator process
    info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
    info: [debug] Killing any other simulator daemons
    info: [debug] On a real device; cannot clean device state
    info: [debug] Not setting locale because we're using a real device
    info: [debug] No iOS / app preferences to set
    info: [debug] Starting iOS device log capture via deviceconsole
    info: [debug] Not pre-launching simulator
    info: [debug] Creating iDevice object with udid 1e2c8589a84393e8c7b1fa801cbc69d6d3a9d222
    info: [debug] Couldn't find ideviceinstaller, trying built-in at /Users/dmytrohorban/Desktop/appium/build/libimobiledevice-macosx/ideviceinstaller
    info: [debug] Checking app install status using: /Users/dmytrohorban/Desktop/appium/build/fruitstrap/fruitstrap isInstalled --id 1e2c8589a84393e8c7b1fa801cbc69d6d3a9d222 --bundle com.testapp.test
    info: [debug] App is installed.
    info: [debug] fullReset not requested. No need to install.
    info: [debug] Starting command proxy.
    info: [debug] Instruments socket server started at /tmp/instruments_sock
    info: [debug] Starting instruments
    info: [debug] Instruments is at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments
    info: Launching instruments
    info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 1e2c8589a84393e8c7b1fa801cbc69d6d3a9d222
    info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 1e2c8589a84393e8c7b1fa801cbc69d6d3a9d222 com.testapp.test -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/dmytrohorban/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-b578988031d7fc8c.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
    info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
    info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
    info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2014-10-23 13:25:16.625 instruments[4352:2007] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
    info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2014-10-23 13:25:18.638 instruments[4352:6703] Automation Instrument ran into an exception while trying to run the script.  UIAScriptAgentSignaledException
    info: [debug] [INST] 2014-10-23 10:25:18 +0000 Fail: An error occurred while trying to run the script.
    info: [debug] [INST] Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 1.470197s; Output : /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace)
    info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 0
    info: [debug] Killall instruments
    info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
    info: [debug] Attempting to retry launching instruments, this is retry #1
    info: [debug] Killall iOS Simulator
    info: Launching instruments
    info: [debug] Attempting to run app on real device with UDID 1e2c8589a84393e8c7b1fa801cbc69d6d3a9d222
    info: [debug] Spawning instruments with command: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/instruments -t /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/PlugIns/AutomationInstrument.xrplugin/Contents/Resources/Automation.tracetemplate -D /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace -w 1e2c8589a84393e8c7b1fa801cbc69d6d3a9d222 com.testapp.test -e UIASCRIPT "/Users/dmytrohorban/Library/Application Support/appium/bootstrap/bootstrap-b578988031d7fc8c.js" -e UIARESULTSPATH /tmp/appium-instruments
    info: [debug] And extra without-delay env: {}
    info: [debug] And launch timeouts (in ms): {"global":90000}
    info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2014-10-23 13:25:25.388 instruments[4356:5e03] WebKit Threading Violation - initial use of WebKit from a secondary thread.
    info: [debug] [INST STDERR] 2014-10-23 13:25:26.485 instruments[4356:5e03] Automation Instrument ran into an exception while trying to run the script.  UIAScriptAgentSignaledException
    info: [debug] [INST] 2014-10-23 10:25:26 +0000 Fail: An error occurred while trying to run the script.
    info: [debug] [INST] Instruments Trace Complete (Duration : 1.466522s; Output : /tmp/appium-instruments/instrumentscli0.trace)
    info: [debug] [INSTSERVER] Instruments exited with code 0
    info: [debug] Killall instruments
    info: [debug] Instruments crashed on startup
```

How I can run Appium tests on iPhone 5S device (iOS 8.1) ?

Comment: Try again after adding bundleId in the capablitites

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you start Appium using this command:

> node appium.js -U 1e2c8589a84393e8c7b1fa801cbc69d6d3a9d222  --app /Users/dmytrohorban/Desktop/Test_builds/Device/TestQS.app;

To me, this seems to suggest you want to use a real iPhone (since you specify the UDID and the log also shows the "Not checking whether simulator is available since we're on a real device") but use the .app application (which runs on simulators only).

If you want to run the app on a real device, you should specify the location of your .ipa file instead of the .app file

Otherwise, you can run appium without the -U parameter and specify a simulator name in the capabilities to use appium with the .app file.